# Read file and find index of value in array in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran77, abaqus

I am making user subroutine file of Abaqus.
However, in reading a file I met with a difficulty.
Since, it is Fortran 77 based, it is so hard to find exact solution.
My intention is to read a file where an 1X1 array is include. Then, to find an index of a value in the array.

My code to read a file is :

```
open (unit=99,file='D:\SIMULATION\dist.txt',status='old')
read (99,*) dist
close (99)
```

And the code for finding index of value in array is:

```
loc=minloc(abs(dist-1),1)
```

I think `minloc` is for Fortran 90, right?
Is there any function in Fortran 77 similar to `minloc`?

Comment: `minloc` is f95, but there is no way you are using abaqus with a f77-only compiler.

Comment: What is dist? Please show more code! Show the declaration. `read (99,*) dist` is also Fortran 90. I don't think you have to avoid Fortran 90.

Comment: Ok. thank you. I will try using Fortran 90 or 95.

Comment: maybe you misunderstood. Abaqus only works with recent intel compilers, so you are already using f2003 at least.  Your abaqus log file will show the compiler version.  What actual problem do you have?

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood. It was not compiler version problem. Instead, in the 'minloc' function, 'An array-valued argument is required in this context' message occurred. 'dist' is an array, and formed [1,2,3] like that. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: That error message only occurs if you use `minloc` on a scalar value. In other words, the code shown so far should compile and run fine as long as `dist` is an array. Also, there is a red herring regarding the F77 limitation...some of the OP's confusion may be due to the fact that Abaqus docs and examples continue to use F77-style fixed formatting, although any operation supported by the Intel compiler version used is valid code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've shown should compile and run as expected. I'm assuming that you are actually reading a **1xN** array and that when you said "1X1" it was a typo - otherwise, there's no point in using `minloc`.

However, the error message you reported in a comment (`An array-valued argument is required in this context`) only occurs if you use the `minloc` intrinsic on a scalar value. Thus, my guess is that you did not declare `dist` as an array. Here is a quick example of what I mean:

```
! The contents of 'values.txt' are: -3.1, 4.1, 5.9, 2.6, -5.4
! Values may be separated by commas or blanks.

program get_min_dist
    implicit none
    real :: x                   ! <-- Cannot be used to represent an array.
    real, dimension(5) :: a     ! <-- An array of 5 reals. Do this instead.
    integer :: loc, funit1

    open(newunit=funit1, file="values.txt", status="old")
    read(funit1,*) x
    rewind(funit1)
    read(funit1,*) a
    close(funit1)

    loc = minloc(abs(a-1),1)    ! <-- I'm assuming there is a reason to 
                                ! subtract 1 from all values in the array

    ! loc = minloc(abs(x-1),1)  ! <-- Error 'An array-valued arg is required`
    print*, "x=",x
    print*, "a=",a
    print*, "index=", loc
    print*, "value=", a(loc)
end program get_min_dist
```

With `read(funit1,*) x` the first value will be assigned when the file is read, resulting in the error message you have seen. With the array `a`, however, you get the expected output.

Your confusion regarding the need to use F77 compatible code may be due to the fact that Abaqus continues to provide examples and docs with F77-style fixed-formatting, and requires Fortran source code to be given the **.f** or **.for** extension<sup>**1**</sup>. By default, this extension tells `ifort` to expect fixed-format code<sup>**2**</sup>. However, any Fortran features supported by the version of the compiler you use is still valid - even in fixed-format, if you must. For further information about the availability of features from different Fortran versions, see your (Intel Fortran) documentation.

<sub><sup>**1**</sup> I'd be glad to know if this can be changed somehow, e.g. to allow the `.f90` extension.</sub>

<sub><sup>**2**</sup> This setting can be changed in the Abaqus environment file, at least for the versions I've used (6.9-6.14). I don't think that has changed with newer releases, but maybe. I don't recommend changing it if you share the environment with other users without their consent, especially for newbies.</sub>

Comment: you can put a directive in a local `abaqus_v6.env` file and not bother other users.  (  `compile_fortran = compile_fortran+["-free",]`  seems to work.)

Comment: @agentp Good point, that works too. Anything to avoid fixed-format.

Comment: Thank you. I solved my probelm according the your advice.

Comment: Ok, good! Also, please remember the advice given by VladimirF and HighPerformanceMark to provide a minimal working example (MWE) so that next time your question might be answered much more quickly.

Comment: @agentp, I just found the `!DIR$ FREEFORM` directive. No need to place edited .env files with `-free` into the cwd, and no changes to the system default .env file either. Nice.